# Rendering component with its state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm really confused now about lifecycle hooks. Here's my code:

App.js:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arrayOfComponents: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
  //i get the properties from the server which responds with the database's elements
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(arrayOfData => this.setState({arrayOfComponents: arrayOfData}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state) //first returns empty array, after the mount returns the db's array of elements
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Component name='First' id={1} componentsComponents={this.state.arrayOfComponents} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Component.js:

```js
class Component extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            componentsComponents: []
        }
    }
    //here i was tried with componentDidMount, componentWillMount to set the
    //this.props.componentsComponents to this.state.componentsComponents
    //but it didn't work
    renderComponents = () => {
        if(this.state.componentsComponents.length){
            return this.state.componentsComponents.filter(c => c.inhertedFromId === this.props.id).map(c => {
                return <Component name={c.name} id={c.id} componentsComponents={this.props.componentsComponents} />
            })
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.renderComponents()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So what i want to do is to the components renders themselves, depending on the array they get from the `App.js`. But how to set the state before the render happens? Can i somehow ask the component to render again if it did mount? Or any other solutions?

Comment: when the `state` is updated (or new props are received) the `render` method will get invoked again.

Comment: Obvious issue, you're not calling `this.renderComponents` in your render method, so you're trying to render a function rather than the result of its execution.

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot the call. The problem is, if i call, still nothing happens.

Comment: `Component` is not getting the data via props...

Comment: It's react basics, see @RIYAJ KHAN answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bring Filter Up To App

Here it appears you are not calling renderComponents, and you are also trying to render a Component inside itself, which is difficult to reason about. Bring the renderComponents function up to App, and render the data using Component inside of App, and simply pass props down to a stateless Component, which may be a simpler solution to represent the data.

If a recursive call is indeed the best way to represent this data, may need to use getDerivedStateFromProps to move props into state on update, if you wish to store that data in state - something like:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
  return {
    componentsComponents: nextProps.componentsComponents
  }
}
```

Added to Component.

Comment: What's wrong with a component that render's itself? that's a classic recursive call.

Comment: You're right, it can be done, actually. I just find this a difficult way to represent a data flow as simple as filtering a bit of data and then rendering it with a component... could lead to confusion like this.

Comment: It can get confusing, i'm not sure what is the OP after but if it is a tree-view then recursive component is probably the way to go.

Comment: gDSFP() works perfect! I don't understand the working of it, but it does it well.

Comment: great! it's relatively new, you can read more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops - updates your state based on received props - you can define rules and derive a different state based on props, as well, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign     `this.props.componentsComponents` in constructor itself only.

```
constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={
                componentsComponents: this.props.componentsComponents||[]
            }
        }
```

Comment: It returns an empty array even if i remove `||[]`, when i log it into the console.